# Dashed line in Qlik Sense chart?

Tags: charts, linechart, qliksense

Asking this here because I can't post on Qliks forums with my work account--hopefully this is inline with the rules.

My task seems simple enough, I want to create a line chart with two lines: one solid line and one dashed line. Super easy to do in Excel. From consulting Google, it seems that this is impossible to do in Qlik Sense. It's 2019 is it not? Why wouldn't something this simple be built in, there must be a workaround right? Hoping someone here has Qlik Sense experience and can give me advice.

PS: The "combo chart" workaround suggested on some forums doesn't work if you have more than one dimension--which in this case I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two separate line styles is a limitation of the default line graph itself, not so much Qlik. If you haven't already, I would recommend checking out Qlik Branch at https://developer.qlik.com/garden, as to do what you're wanting is going to take an extension.

I know of an extension called AnyChart that can do a dotted line alongside a normal line, [See a picture here.](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/3e554642a07924401450cfff271b47980222ab69/687474703a2f2f63646e2e616e7963686172742e636f6d2f696d616765732f716c696b2d73637265656e732f6c696e655f322e6a7067), among a lot of other things.

Visit AnyChart's Qlik Branch page here: https://developer.qlik.com/garden/58cf59cd61d353a813f4a37e

GitHub repo at https://github.com/AnyChart/AnyChart-Qlik

Once you download the folder, place it into your `Documents\Qlik\Sense\Extensions\` directory and reload Qlik.